# How to dynamically add the rows in the MUI for user to edit and add?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my example, where I am reading the values i.e. normRules and then applying it to dynamically generate the rows. However, I want the user to be able to add a new row and
edit the values when the add button is pressed. In the add submit click, I am simply appending the array with an empty object. However, I see that it simply adding an empty object i.e. a blank row. How can I add a row that a user is mandated to add the values in that row when a user clicks the add button? Here is my sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-c8hf16?file=/Test.js